# How to validate huge number of columns efficiently

Tags: c#

I have a below DataTable which can have any number of rows and column in each row is around 40.
i am trying to validate each column and if it fails copying that row in a new table.

```
private void ValidateRows(DataTable csvDataTable)
{
    DataTable invalidatedTable = new DataTable();
    invalidatedTable = csvDataTable.Clone();

    // Loop over all the rows in the datatable
    foreach (DataRow row in csvDataTable.Rows)
    {
        bool invalidated = false;

        if (row["ID"].ToString() == "")
        {
            invalidated = true;
            row["ID"] = "not valid";
        }
        if (row["Name"].ToString() != "test")
        {
            invalidated = true;
        }
        //and rest of the validation

        //if invalid
        if (invalidated)
        {           
            invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }
    } // End Loop  
}
```

if there an efficient way where we can do the validation?
like any pattern we can apply for validating a row which looks cleaner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add automatically the invalidated record without using a boolean variable:

```
foreach (DataRow row in csvDataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row["ID"].ToString() == "" || row["Name"].ToString() != "test")
            {
                invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                if (row["ID"].ToString() == "") 
                    row["ID"] = "not valid";
            }
        }
```

This looks cleaner and readable.

Comment: That would require that the line `invalidatedTable.Rows.Add()` be included in every `if` statement.

Comment: yep , agree with @BJMyers

Comment: Okay let me edit that, I didn't see the other boolean condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking every column, even if some earlier columns have invalidated the row. If you are expecting a lot of invalidated rows, then this will significantly impact your performance.

If the checks don't have side effects (like the `Name` check), then feel free to skip it.

```
if (!invalidated && row["Name"].ToString() != "test")
{
    invalidated = true;
}
```

Without more details on what it means for a row to be invalid, I'm not sure if there is much more you can do.

Comment: yep and there are 40 columns which is concerning.

Answer (score 0):

If most of your validation conditions are simple (and have no side effects), you could store each of those conditions as a delegate and then loop through them.

```
private void ValidateRows(DataTable csvDataTable)
{
    DataTable invalidatedTable = new DataTable();
    invalidatedTable = csvDataTable.Clone();

    List<Func<DataRow, bool>> validators = new List<Func<DataRow, bool>>
    {
        row => row["ID"].ToString() == "",
        row => row["Name"].ToString() != "test",
    };

    // Loop over all the rows in the datatable
    foreach (DataRow row in csvDataTable.Rows)
    {
        bool valid = validators.All(validator => validator(row));
        if (!valid)
        {
            invalidatedTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }

    } // End Loop  
}
```

Each validation method becomes one additional entry in the `validators` list.

(Note that the call to `validators.All` is short-circuiting - as soon as one of the validations fails, none of the other validations are run for that particular row.)

---

The downside to this approach is that performing side effects for particular validations (such as setting `row["ID"] = "not valid"` in your original code) can get cumbersome.  You'll either need to enhance the delegate to be more than just a one-liner, like this:

```
List<Func<DataRow, bool>> validators = new List<Func<DataRow, bool>>
{
    row =>
    {
        bool idIsEmpty = row["ID"].ToString() == "";
        if (idIsEmpty) row["ID"] = "not valid";
        return !idIsEmpty;
    },
    row => row["Name"].ToString() != "test",
};
```

or pull those cases out into separate functions:

```
List<Func<DataRow, bool>> validators = new List<Func<DataRow, bool>>
{
    RowIdValidation,
    row => row["Name"].ToString() != "test",
};

... snip ...

private static bool RowIdValidation(DataRow row)
{
    bool idIsEmpty = row["ID"].ToString() == "";
    if (idIsEmpty) row["ID"] = "not valid";
    return !idIsEmpty;
}
```

Furthermore (as noted by @MotKohn), you will need to modify your code to prevent `All`'s short-circuit behavior from skipping side effects, probably by using a plain-old `foreach` loop instead.

TL;DR - If you have side effects happening after your validations, switching to this style might make your code a *lot* harder to follow.

Comment: By using this code you gain what msitt pointes out that you are not continuing to validate if one column is invalid. On the other hand if there are desired side effects on later columns you won't be getting them.

Comment: yep, its not continuing :( so only way is "if" conditions under foreach loop ?